# Programmatically obtaining the number of colors used in an image

Tags: language-agnostic, image, image-processing, image-manipulation, colors

Question:

- Given an image in PNG format, what is the simplest way to programmatically obtain the number of colors **used** in the image?

Constraints:

- The solution will be integreted into a shell script running under Linux, so any solution that fits in such an environment will do.
- Please note that the "color capacity of the image file" does not necessarily correspond to "colors used". Example: In an image file with a theoretical color capacity of 256 colors only say 7 colors might be in actual use. I want to obtain the number of colors actually **used**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why write your own program?

If you're doing this with a shell script, you can use the `netpbm` utilities:

```
count = `pngtoppm png_file | ppmhist -noheader | wc -l`
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Image.getcolors](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.getcolors) method in Python Imaging Library seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Fun.  There doesn't appear to be any guaranteed method of doing this;  in the worst case you'll need to scan the image and interpret every pixel, in the best possible case the PNG will be using a palette and you can just check there.

Even in the palette case, though, you're not guaranteed that every entry is used -- so you're (at best) getting an upper bound.

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Contents.html

.. and the chunk info here:

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Chunks.html

Comment: he specifically wants the **actual** number of colours used, so an upper bound based on the colour depth or palette isn't good enough

Comment: Hey, nice.  I answer correctly, then expand a bit on my answer to give a potentially useful back-of-the-envelope addition, and you rate me down for it?  Remind me never to add color or context to my statements.. I should have stopped after the semi-colon.

Comment: actually you should have stopped after "interpret every pixel"

Answer (score 1):

Alnitak's solution is nice :)  I really should get to know netpbm and imagemagick etc. better some time.

Just FYI, as a simple and very general solution: loop through each pixel in the image, getting the r,g,b color values as a single integer.  Look for that integer in a list.  If it's not there, add it.  When finished with all the pixels, print the number of colors in the list.

If you want to count occurences, use a hashmap/dictionary instead of a simple list, incrementing the key's value (a counter) if found in the dictionary already.  If not found, add it with a starting counter value of 1.

Comment: "Loop through each pixel in the image [...]" isn't that just a more detailed re-statement of the problem?

Comment: Arguably, any program is a more detailed restatement of the problem :)  The question is whether the asker knew that, and whether it helps to tell him.  I made a call based on how the question was written, and decided that he might not have known it.